# Rendering directives with Pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using PURE to render a directive ([docs](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/rendering-with-directives/))

**HTML**

```
  <td class="timer ">
    <span class="active_col_duration1">
    00:00:00
  </span>
  </td>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $('.timer').render(obj, directivetimer);

var directivetimer = {
    'span': {
        'act<-active':{

            '.active_col_duration1+': function(arg){
                conf_time_sec = arg.item.duration1;
                if(refreshIntervalId>0)
                    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
                    conf_time_sec = parseInt(conf_time_sec)+1;
                    $(".active_col_duration1").html(("" +conf_time_sec).toHHMMSS());
                },1000);
                return " " +  (""+arg.item.duration1).toHHMMSS();
            },
        }
    }
};
```

However, I get `Uncaught pure error: The node ".active_col_duration1+ was not found in the template: <span class="active_col_duration1"`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What an amazingly bad name for a library... *(The lib looks cool, though.)*

Comment: Did you try removing the plus from `'.active_col_duration1+'`?

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, it's the same error. `+` is used to return value of the function to the class - http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/using-js-functions-with-directives/